# how to append ajax data to html div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

```
url=url+calsign+"&dept="+deptString+"&dest="+destString+"&deptDate="+flightdate+"&deptTime="+flighttime+"&flightTime="+flyingtime+"&pilot="+'Mani'+":"+'Gnana'+"+&copilot="+'Mani'+":"+'Gnana'+"&crew="+'Mani'+":"+'Gnana'+"&userName="+user; 
$.get(url, function(data) {
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
var div = '<div class="row" id="flightsummary"><div class="col-md-6"><div class="summary"><p> Transportation Start Time ='+data[i]['TRANSPORT_START_TIME'];+'</p><p> Reporting Start Time ='+data[i]['REPORTING_START_TIME'];+'</p><p> Chocks Off Time ='+data[i]['CHOCKS_OFF_TIME'];+'</p><p> Chocks On Time ='+data[i]['CHOCKS_ON_TIME'];+'</p><p>+Duty End Time ='+data[i]['DUTY_END_TIME'];+'</p><p> Flight Time ='+ data[i]['FLIGHT_TIME'];+'</p><p> Flight Duty Period ='+data[i]['FLIGHT_DUTY_PERIOD'];+'</p></p></div></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="summary summary-right"><p> Rest Period Start Time ='+data[i]['REST_PERIOD_START_TIME'];+'</p><p> Minimum Rest Hours ='+data[i]['MINIMUM_REST_HOURS'];+'</p><p> Next Transportation Start Time <span class="calendar"></span> ='+data[i]['NEXT_TRNS_START_TIME'];+'</p><p> Next Reporting Time <span class="calendar"></span> ='+data[i]['NEXT_REPORTING_TIME'];+'</p><p> Next Earliest Take Off <span class="calendar"></span> ='+data[i]['NEXT_EARLIEST_TAKE_OFF'];+'</p><p> Last Landing Time <span class="calendar"></span> ='+data[i]['LAST_LANDING_TIME'];+'</p></div></div></div>;';

                $('#summary').append(div);
});



        }).fail(function() {
            console.log("failed to load");
        }).done(function() {
            console.log("success to load");
        });
```

I am trying to append a div to html which has response of data,able to see data seperately through console logs but am unable to append all data to html,only first data is printing as (

`Transportation Start Time ='+data[i]['TRANSPORT_START_TIME'];+`

) rest values are not printing,please help me to solve this,Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you see how your question is displayed? Is it readable and understandable by **you** first? See the **[tour]** first.

Comment: sorry for that,in a hurry kept like that,could you please tell me how to do it????????

Comment: See the edit, buddy.

Comment: ok thanks for that and please tell me how to do it????

Comment: I am not sure. So let others answer it for you.

Comment: @vetukurignanadeep you made the code messy. This is not how to write optimized code using jquery. I would suggest go through jquery basic tutorials on data binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the construction of div element you have used single quotes as main string and double quotes as attributes value. The mismatch of quotes is happening hence it is not considering as valid html.

Please construct the html like below :

```
       var div = '<div class="row" id="flightsummary"><div class="col-md-6"><div class="summary"><p> Transportation Start Time =' + data[i]["TRANSPORT_START_TIME"]
     + '</p><p> Reporting Start Time =' + data[i]["REPORTING_START_TIME"] +
      '</p><p> Chocks Off Time =' + data[i]["CHOCKS_OFF_TIME"]
     + '</p><p> Chocks On Time =' + data[i]["CHOCKS_ON_TIME"]
      + '</p><p>+Duty End Time =' + data[i]["DUTY_END_TIME"]
      + '</p><p> Flight Time =' + data[i]["FLIGHT_TIME"]
      + '</p><p> Flight Duty Period =' + data[i]["FLIGHT_DUTY_PERIOD"]
       + '</p></p></div></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="summary summary-right"><p> Rest Period Start Time ='
       + data[i]["REST_PERIOD_START_TIME"]
       + '</p><p> Minimum Rest Hours ='
        + data[i]["MINIMUM_REST_HOURS"]
        + '</p><p> Next Transportation Start Time <span class="calendar"></span> ='
        + data[i]["NEXT_TRNS_START_TIME"]
        + '</p><p> Next Reporting Time <span class="calendar"></span> ='
        + data[i]["NEXT_REPORTING_TIME"]
         + '</p><p> Next Earliest Take Off <span class="calendar"></span> ='
         + data[i]["NEXT_EARLIEST_TAKE_OFF"] + '</p><p> Last Landing Time <span class="calendar"></span> =' 
         + data[i]["LAST_LANDING_TIME"]; +'</p></div></div></div>;';
```

Comment: Eventhough i have used double quotes am unable to print values,